# SortedSet<T> and anonymous IComparer<T> in the constructor is not working

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, anonymous-function

How come anonymous functions works as arguments on methods, but not in constructor arguments?

---

If I create a `List<string>`, it has a Sort method with the following signature:

```
public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer)
```

where the following works:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Sort( (a,b) => a.CompareTo(b) );
```

SortedSet has a constructor with a similar signature:

```
public SortedSet(IComparer<T> comparer)
```

but this fails when using an anonymous function in the constructor. The following is not valid:

```
SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>( (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) );
```

Creating a sorting class works fine as expected:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    { return a.CompareTo(b); }
}

SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>( new MyComparer() );
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That it is because [the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395024.aspx) accepts an `IComparer<T>` (interface), rather than a `Comparison<T>` (delegate). Anon-methods / lambdas can support delegates, but not (directly) interfaces. It is pretty easy to wrap, though - for example:

```
class FuncComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Comparison<T> comparison;
    public FuncComparer(Comparison<T> comparison) {
        this.comparison = comparison;
    }
    public int Compare(T x, T y) {
        return comparison(x, y); }
}
```

Now you can use:

```
SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>(
      new FuncComparer<string>( (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and wrapper code. I see now that that I was using the Comparison<T> and not IComparere<T> on sort.

Answer (score 36):

The .NET Framework 4.5 release introduced the factory method `Comparer<T>.Create`:

```
var set = new SortedSet<string>(
    Comparer<string>.Create((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)));
```

Comment: What if I want to make the set differentiate between keys but sorted by values?

Answer (score 6):

The explanation is great that SortedSet accepts an interface but not a delegate.(But Java does).

Because of that, the .Net guys provide a factory method to create such an object, so you don't need to define a new class for that.

```
var set = new SortedSet<string>( 
    Comparer<string>.Create((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I your case List.Sort uses this signature

```
public void Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)
```

but not this

```
public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer)
```